# Alert is issued multiple times in chrome extension background js

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When onUpdated in chrome extension background js, alert is executed several times instead of one. What is the reason? Am I using it wrong?

manifest.json

```
{
      "manifest_version": 2,

      "name": "불법 토토사이트 감지기",
      "description": "불법 토토사이트를 감지해주는 사이트입니다.",
      "version": "1.0",
      "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
      "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
      },
      "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "<all_urls>",
        "contextMenus"
      ]
  }
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tab) {
                var domain = tab.url;
                var google = 'https://www.google.co.kr/';

                alert(domain);
                // if(tab){
                //     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                //     var data = {
                //        
                //         birth: 123,
                //     };
                //     xhr.open('POST', 'http://soylatte.kr:3000/image/check');
                //     xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                //     xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
                // }
                //



        })
```

Comment: Tabs.onUpdated event fires each time any tab is updated. Update your question and explain what do you want to achieve and what issues  you facing.

Comment: So what would be the most appropriate event if you examined url and approached a particular url?

Comment: In the call back you will receive changeInfo use its status to determine the update is complete and ready url from it to add condition and do what you want to do.